# Problem with Simple HTML DOM Parser in laravel

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm using the [laravel-html-dom-parser](https://github.com/ammadeuss/laravel-html-dom-parser) package for Laravel.

I want to get the value of a span that has an `itemprop` attribute with a value of "price" so I wrote this code but it displays an error.

```
$name = HTMLDomParser::str_get_html('http://www.tgju.org/chart/price_dollar_rl')->find('li > span > itemprop="price"')[0]->plaintext;
```

The error I get is:

> preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 4

Comment: What is your PHP version ? It seems that `sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser` used by `laravel-html-dom-parser` [is not compatible with PHP 7.3](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser/issues/64). There is an alternative : https://github.com/Kub-AT/php-simple-html-dom-parser.

Comment: @UgoT. i'm using php 7.3. In this package that you introduced how can i get value of a span that have itemprop="price" attribute

Comment: I've never use this lib but something like that should return you what you want : `$name = HTMLDomParser::str_get_html('http://www.tgju.org/chart/price_dollar_rl')->find("li > span[itemprop='price']", 0)->plaintext;`

Comment: That's just a modern wrapper around a very dated and poorly written piece of code. There are far better alternatives, including PHP's built-in functions.

Comment: @miken32 thanks, if i do not use this package how can do this with PHP's built-in functions

Comment: You can take a look at PHP Dom module : https://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php and http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in avoiding this library, which is just a wrapper around a piece of code from like 2010, you can use native code:

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtmlFile('http://www.tgju.org/chart/price_dollar_rl');
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//li/span[@itemprop="price"]');
if ($nodes->length) {
    echo $nodes[0]->textContent;
}
```

Output:

```
153,500
```

The XPath syntax can be complicated, but for anything that can be represented in a CSS-style expression it's pretty easy to understand.

I haven't looked, but I'd be surprised if there weren't proper DOM libraries for Laravel that wrapped this native functionality.

Comment: Looks like [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) is a good modern alternative if you want to use a library. It provides a nice front end to Symfony's BrowserKit and DomCrawler classes. You can filter with XPath or CSS-style selectors.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to retrieve remote HTML using the simple DOM parser is to use the `file_get_html` function. The `str_get_html` function you are using here is used to initialize a Simple DOM object from a HTML string NOT from a remote source.

Additionally, to return the span with itemprop="price" you wouldn't use the `>` immediate child selector but the attribute selector `span[itemprop=price]`. The syntax of the simple DOM query selectors is almost identical to the ones used in Javascript, more info on which can be found on the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Together:

```
$name = HTMLDomParser::file_get_html('http://www.http://www.tgju.org/chart/price_dollar_rl')->find('li > span[itemprop=price]')[0]->plaintext
```

Hopefully that answers your question, but if you get stuck you can consult the Simple DOM documentation on [Sourceforge](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm).